# Return function results based on condition - PHP

Tags: php, php-7.3

I have the following code

```
public function create(){
  return self::checkQuantity();
  return self::checkSameLocation();
  return self::someAnotherFunction();
  return self::someMoreFunction();
  ..
  ..
  ..

}

public function checkQuantity(){
  if(someCondition){
     return [foo,bar];
  }
}


public function checkSameLocation(){
  if(someCondition){
     return [foo,bar];
  }
}
```

I would like to return function inside `create()` only if it function inside it returns something else continue executing the `create()` function.

Based on the example:

- `create()` gets called
- if `checkQuantity` returns nothing then continue with `checkSameLocation()` without returning `checkQuantity()` function

NOTE: There could be multiple function calls inside create() sometimes, I would like to avoid using `if statement` checks.

Comment: Without doing if checks, because if there are 10 functions calls that would make it messy.

Comment: Without `if` checks you can't check __if__ nothing returned from first function

Comment: Im not sure what it is your functions return, are these functions wrapped in a class? You cant check if nothing returned from a function because it will always return null.

Comment: In terms of OOD, I guess a suitable solution would be [chain of responsibility](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility/php/example#example-1)

Comment: @AndriiFilenko thanks, I will look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function create(){
    return self::checkQuantity()
           ?? self::checkSameLocation()
           ?? self::someAnotherFunction(); //and so on
}
```

See [Null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Comment: This is much better than `if.. else`, much cleaner. I was looking for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function create(){
  $data = function1();
  if ($data) { 
    return $data;
  }

  $data = function2();
  if ($data) { 
    return $data;
  }

  $data = function3();
  if ($data) { 
    return $data;
  }

  // ...

  return function42();
}
```

This can lead to another solution like:

```
public function create(){
  $functions = ['func1', 'func2', 'func3',]; // etc
  foreach ($functions as $func) {
    $data = $func();
    if ($data) { 
      return $data;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

(in this case, I've moved all your check code into polymorphic classes; the same could be achieved with methods in the current class per your question, but I think it's neater this way)

```
$checks = [new checkClass1, new checkClass2, new checkClass3, ...];

foreach ($checks as $check) {
    $result = $check->runCheck();
    if ($result) {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But coalesce operator is much cleaner approaches for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `if` and a temporary variable.

```
public function create(){
  $a = self::checkQuantity();
  if(empty($a)) { 
    return self::checkSameLocation();
  } else {
    return $a;
  }
}

public function checkQuantity(){
  if(someCondition){
     return [foo,bar];
  }
}


public function checkSameLocation(){
  if(someCondition){
     return [foo,bar];
  }
}
```

Comment: What if, there is more than 2 functions? Please check updated question.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the perfect use case for the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)

```
public function create(){
  return self::checkQuantity() ?? self::checkSameLocation() ?? self::someAnotherFunction() ?? return self::someMoreFunction()...
}
```

You can chain as many function calls as you want. That line will return the first value that's not null. Since returning nothing from a function effectively equals returning a null value, it'll work as you want.